# Sharepoint Master page in Sitepages?

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages

I need to create a custom header like a banner or something in my SharePoint site but when I set the master page as site master page nothing happens, so i need to see my custom master page header in my site pages and not in my admin, so what should I do to get it work?

I tried to set as default master page so it works but it appears also in my admin and I don't want that, I just want it in my site.

I'm using SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

What I could get from the Question is you want your custom MasterPage on all the Pages except Admin.

you can set it as default Master page and for the admin page you can change the master page using SharePoint designer:

At the top of code just edit the Master page name you want to use. in This case it will be default.master

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage"
**MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"** meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full"       %>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, where can i find that file? thanks

Comment: @Ron At top click on site Actions -> Edit in SharePoint Designer
SharePoint Designer will open
now In Left navigation bar Click on "Site pages" from there you can open the code of your admin page.